# Discord Bot Logger

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, discord, discord.js

Could someone help me to get that script working? I guess it's not updated to the newest Discord API.

I just need three things: A logger with nickname change, username change and avatar change.

Already made myself working logger with a role change and a welcome message when someone new just gets in but these three seems to be broken as hell.

```js
bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', function(guild, oldMember, newMember) {

    //declare changes
    var Changes = {
        unknown: 0,
        addedRole: 1,
        removedRole: 2,
        username: 3,
        nickname: 4,
        avatar: 5
    };
    var change = Changes.unknown;

    //check if username changed
    if (newMember.user.username != oldMember.user.username)
        change = Changes.username;

    //check if nickname changed
    if (newMember.nickname != oldMember.nickname)
        change = Changes.nickname;

    //check if avatar changed
    if (newMember.user.avatarURL != oldMember.user.avatarURL)
        change = Changes.avatar;

    //log to console
    switch (change) {
        case Changes.unknown:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][UPDUSR] ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
            break;


        case Changes.username:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][UPDUSRNM] ' + oldMember.user.username + '#' + oldMember.user.discriminator +
                ' is now ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
            break;
        case Changes.nickname:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][UPDUSRNK] ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator +
                (oldMember.nickname != null ? ' (' + oldMember.nickname + ')' : '') +
                (newMember.nickname != null ? ' is now ' + newMember.nickname : ' no longer has a nickname.'));
            break;
        case Changes.avatar:
            console.log('[' + guild.name + '][UPDAVT] ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
            break;
    }

    //post in the guild's log channel
    var log = guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
    if (log != null) {
        switch (change) {
            case Changes.unknown:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Update]** ' + newMember);
                break;


            case Changes.username:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Username Changed]** ' + newMember + ': Username changed from ' +
                    oldMember.user.username + '#' + oldMember.user.discriminator + ' to ' +
                    newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
                break;
            case Changes.nickname:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Nickname Changed]** ' + newMember + ': ' +
                    (oldMember.nickname != null ? 'Changed nickname from ' + oldMember.nickname +
                        +newMember.nickname : 'Set nickname') + ' to ' +
                    (newMember.nickname != null ? newMember.nickname + '.' : 'original username.'));
                break;
            case Changes.avatar:
                log.sendMessage('**[User Avatar Changed]** ' + newMember);
                break;
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The following line is causing your program to error:

```js
    var log = guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL);
```

In discord.js v12, you need to use a function and use the `.cache.`

Here is the corrected ver:

```js
    var log = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == CHANNEL);
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are a few issues:**

1. The `guildMemberUpdate` event only passes two parameters: **oldMember** and **newMember**. It does not pass a **guild** parameter as shown in your code.
2. Since no **guild** parameter is passed, you need to change all references to `guild` with `newMember.guild`.
3. `guild.channels` now requires `.cache` to be appended on the end: `guild.channels.cache`. For more information, read the [Discord.js migration guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html).
4. The [`Discord.Collection()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) [`.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) method now only accepts a function.
5. `.sendMessage()` needs to be replaced with [`.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send).
6. `.avatarURL` needs to be replaced with [`.displayAvatarURL()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL).

*Side Note: why don't you use [`newMember.user.tag`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=tag) instead of `newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator`?*

**Here is the modified code:**

```js
bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', function(oldMember, newMember) {

    //declare changes
    var Changes = {
        unknown: 0,
        addedRole: 1,
        removedRole: 2,
        username: 3,
        nickname: 4,
        avatar: 5
    };
    var change = Changes.unknown;

    //check if username changed
    if (newMember.user.username !== oldMember.user.username)
        change = Changes.username;

    //check if nickname changed
    if (newMember.nickname !== oldMember.nickname)
        change = Changes.nickname;

    //check if avatar changed
    if (newMember.user.displayAvatarURL() !== oldMember.user.displayAvatarURL())
        change = Changes.avatar;

    //log to console
    switch (change) {
        case Changes.unknown:
            console.log('[' + newMember.guild.name + '][UPDUSR] ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
            break;


        case Changes.username:
            console.log('[' + newMember.guild.name + '][UPDUSRNM] ' + oldMember.user.username + '#' + oldMember.user.discriminator +
                ' is now ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
            break;
        case Changes.nickname:
            console.log('[' + newMember.guild.name + '][UPDUSRNK] ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator +
                (oldMember.nickname != null ? ' (' + oldMember.nickname + ')' : '') +
                (newMember.nickname != null ? ' is now ' + newMember.nickname : ' no longer has a nickname.'));
            break;
        case Changes.avatar:
            console.log('[' + newMember.guild.name + '][UPDAVT] ' + newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
            break;
    }

    //post in the guild's log channel
    var log = newMember.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === CHANNEL);
    if (log) {
        switch (change) {
            case Changes.unknown:
                log.send('**[User Update]** ' + newMember);
                break;


            case Changes.username:
                log.send('**[User Username Changed]** ' + newMember + ': Username changed from ' +
                    oldMember.user.username + '#' + oldMember.user.discriminator + ' to ' +
                    newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
                break;
            case Changes.nickname:
                log.send('**[User Nickname Changed]** ' + newMember + ': ' +
                    (oldMember.nickname != null ? 'Changed nickname from ' + oldMember.nickname +
                        +newMember.nickname : 'Set nickname') + ' to ' +
                    (newMember.nickname != null ? newMember.nickname + '.' : 'original username.'));
                break;
            case Changes.avatar:
                log.send('**[User Avatar Changed]** ' + newMember);
                break;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: now i got this:
```TypeError: log.sendMessage is not a function```


Just changed it to ```client.channels.cache.get('MY CHANNEL ID HERE').send```

And seems working.

Comment: But now i have problems with these two:
```newMember.user.displayAvatarURL != oldMember.user.displayAvatarURL```,
```newMember.user != oldMember.user```

Checking avatar change and login change seems not working. The nickname change is working fine. Is this up to date?

Comment: thanks, the ```log.send``` is working great. But i'm still having problems with the avatar and username change annoucement. 
Here is a photo: https://ibb.co/71GfTjZ
The first one message is working good but the next two its avatar and username change. It's not recognized i guess and working as "unknown = 0"

Comment: @FOX I'm stumped.